# Getting audio data in api call

Tags: node.js, api, web-applications

I'm developing an api framework that will handle and manipulate near real time audio data.

How can audio data be presented to our Api? Push call? Reach out and transfer data? Both?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with audio but I suppose it could to be posted as byte?

Comment: yes I suppose that'll work.  Although i'll have to translate it into .wav on the server side for manipulation. Does a similar thing work for all datatypes?